# qTranslate conflicts with SEO-plugins

Tags: plugins, errors, seo, plugin-qtranslate

I have an issue with a clients site. I installed the Yoast SEO-plugin (which i find to be great), but when i activate it i get lot's of error messages (See below).

```
/storage/content/10/104610/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/qtranslate/qtranslate_hooks.php on line 54 Notice: Undefined index: language in /storage/content/10/104610/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/qtranslate/qtranslate_hooks.php on line 55 Notice: Undefined index: language in /storage/content/10/104610/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/qtranslate/qtranslate_hooks.php on line 61 Notice: Undefined index: in /storage/content/10/104610/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/qtranslate/qtranslate_hooks.php on line 61 Notice: Undefined index: language in /storage/content/10/104610/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/qtranslate/qtranslate_hooks.php on line 111 Notice: Undefined index: language in /storage/content/10/104610/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/qtranslate/qtranslate_hooks.php on line 111
```

This error message appears with every SEO-plugin i've tried
What causes this, and how can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the errors tell you it is caused by badly written code.

What you can do: Ask the qtranslate developer to fix these issues, file a proper bug report and add the errors to it. Then wait for an update.